# How can I connect two table in mySQL database and make a calculation with php?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my SQL database (`orders` and `storage`):

"orders" table:

```
id   animal     size
=====================
1     cat         5
2     cat         6
3
```

"storage" table:

```
name     space  
==============
cat       30      
dog       20
```

I need the following result: If `name` does not exists in `animal` of `orders` then print `space`. But if `name` exists in `animal` of `order` then count together all `sizes` of that `animal` and subtract the result from `space` (In this case: 30-(5+6)=19).
So this is what I need to print out in php:

```
list    total  
==============
cat       19      
dog       20
```

---

This is how I tried to solve it:

```
  pdo = Database::connect();

    $sql = 'SELECT orders.animal, orders.size, storage.name, storage.space FROM target LEFT JOIN orders ON storage.name=orders.animal;';
                                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                 $count+ = $row['size'];
                                 $result = $row['space'] - $count;
                                 if ($result == 0) {
                                    echo'    
                                  <tr> 
                                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                                     <td>'.$row['space'].'</td>
                                  </tr>
                                ';
} else {
                                echo'    
                                  <tr> 
                                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                                     <td>'.$result.'</td>
                                  </tr>
                                ';
                            }
                                Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: I feel like you've asked us to solve your homework problem.

Comment: @rbl.usa: sorry I forgot to print my result, I updated my question

Comment: yes I try always to explain my question very clear and easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need arithmetic operations with mysql to get what you want:

> select s.space - sum(o.size) from orders o inner join storag s  where
>   o.animal = s.name

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eef10/4)

Comment: sorry I forgot to print my try in the question, I updated it.

Comment: @vivocomunxino: Thank you, I will have a look a look at your suggestion, I hope I can manage